# Failed building wheel for scrypt - python ethereum (pyethapp)

Tags: python, compilation, pip, virtualenvwrapper, ethereum

My compilation terminated 2 times when installing pyethapp on Ubuntu.

Firstly, I installed packages:

```
apt-get install build-essential automake pkg-config libtool libffi-dev libgmp-dev
```

I made virtualenv and tried to install pyethapp inside *venv* with pip:

```
pip install mytheapp
```

but it crashed with 2 following errors:

1.)

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
                           ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scrypt
```

2.)

```
    scrypt-1.2.0/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c:6:25: fatal error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
     #include <openssl/aes.h>
                             ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/iceing/.virtualenvs/pyethapp/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3PNrgn/scrypt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-SSJvgT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/iceing/.virtualenvs/pyethapp/include/site/python2.7/scrypt" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3PNrgn/scrypt/
```

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need OpenSSL:

```
apt-get install openssl
```

Comment: Is there /usr/include/openssl/aes.h ?

Answer (score 1):

First try installing

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

However, If it still dont work then try installing

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

By now it should work fine.